# Django values method fields param dynamically

Tags: django

How can i pass fields to values method dynamically ?

For example:

```
fields = [‘id’, ‘name’] # could change 
items = Model.objects.all().values(fields)
```

https://github.com/django/django/blob/0c7e880e13b837dd76276c04ebdc338bb76d1379/django/db/models/query.py#L838

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain *what* you aim to achieve.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the question? Share the code, mention your inputs and your aim to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform iterable unpacking when you make a function call, like:

```
fields = ['id', 'name']
#                     unpack ↓
items = Model.objects.values(*fields)
```

this will pass the items in `fields` as individual parameters.

That being said, using [**`.values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) as a way to perform serialization is often an antipattern. You might want to look to the [*serialization* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/serialization/), or work with [*serializers* provided by the Django REST framework [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/).